# Spark 1.5.1 : Inactivity periods between tasks

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

When I examine the event timeline from my Spark Console for my completed batches, I note that there are periods of inactivity between tasks.
Here is one screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh4hA.jpg
How can I explain it ?
Thanks!

Spark 1.5.1
Used with Scala 2.10.5

Comment: Sometimes happen when you have local computations in the driver.

Comment: Tks. Can you tell me more about these maybe local computations ? How to identify them and if there is a way to remove these ?

Comment: Well depends on your code. Some local operations can't be removed as Spark might be computing something locally. What the spark ui shows are only the RDD operations, but anything else is local.